# Maintaining Windows in Workspace after Program Restart

Tags: workspaces

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and firefox recently installed updates and needed to restart. I use all 4 workspaces for different projects of mine, and, after firefox restarted, all of the windows opened in the workspace that was currently open. How can I maintain the windows if firefox, or my computer (etc) needs to restart?